# What is resource isolation for Database security

Tags: databases

Does resource isolation mean different users are assigned different resources such as memory and processors as their own resources?
How such resource isolation improve database security?
Can you please explain in general? I read some text using google. But I still understand nothing.

Comment: can you include some of the links you have read?

Answer (score 0):

Resource isolation can be interpreted in many ways, for now let's take the example where different users are assigned cpu load and memory quotas.

System resource quotas can be assigned to specific processes that may be either untrusted or critical to the system.

By enforcing the quota you make sure that the untrusted application cannot by itself or through subversion consume more system resources that is necessary thereby preventing a denial of service attack and impacting system availability.

By enforcing the quota on trusted, critical processes you are ensuring that the system resources necessary for the system to function are available. This protects the system's availability from attempts to perform a denial of service attack as well.

For example, you have a web server backed by a database, no matter how stressed the web server is (either by attack or design) the database will always have it's portion of system resource to perform it's task.

It all comes down to ensuring Availability (and to an extent, system integrity)